# What is going on with my stock price?

Tags: mutual-funds, price

There are several similar questions on this site but I believe that this one might have a different source than just a reporting glitch.  For some reason, several sources are reporting a drop in the price of FSPTX from somewhere in the upper $185 range to roughly $18 for several days.  Is there a reason for this drop or a way to find out what caused so many sources to be reporting it?

Example from Google Finance:
[image]

Comment: Hey! can the down voter please explain?  I did my research and to my knowledge there is no duplicate question on this site and it is a valid question (if simple) so I do not understand.

Comment: _Presumably_ the down vote was because that person thought the "basic research" someone should do before asking a question should have turned up the existence of the stock-split.

Comment: @TripeHound fair enough, I was researching for articles about the problem, not what caused it but I can definitely see that point of view.

Answer (score 6):

Suspicious factor of ten: smells like a stock split, which inded it is:

> Effective after the close of business on August 10th, 2018, Fidelity executed a 10-for-1 share split on each Class of the Fund. As a result of the split, the number of outstanding shares has been multiplied by 10, with a proportionate decrease in the Net Asset Value (NAV) per share.

https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/summary/316390202

Some sources have presumably adjusted their historical price to take the split into account. Either Google Finance isn't going to do that, or it just hasn't got around to it.